# How can I return a text file content and also the file name?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This return a string that contains the text file content :

```
public static string LoadSingleRecentFile()
    {
        DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(SAVE_FOLDER);
        FileInfo[] saveFiles = directoryInfo.GetFiles("*.txt");
        FileInfo mostRecentFile = null;
        foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in saveFiles)
        {
            if (mostRecentFile == null)
            {
                mostRecentFile = fileInfo;
            }
            else
            {
                if (fileInfo.LastWriteTime > mostRecentFile.LastWriteTime)
                {
                    mostRecentFile = fileInfo;
                }
            }
        }

        if (mostRecentFile != null)
        {
            string saveString = File.ReadAllText(mostRecentFile.FullName);
            return saveString;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And here I'm reading the string content :

```
public void LoadSingleRecentFile()
    {
        string saveString = SaveSystem.LoadSingleRecentFile();

        if (saveString != null)
        {
            SaveObject saveObject = JsonUtility.FromJson<SaveObject>(saveString);

            transform.position = saveObject.position;
            transform.localScale = saveObject.scaling;
            transform.rotation = saveObject.rotation;
        }
    }
```

but instead assign it to a transform like :

```
transform.position = saveObject.position;
```

I need to assign it to the object that the string content belong to this object info.
I have a List objectsToSave list type Transform.  And I need in the LoadSingleRecentFile to loop over this List find the Transform name that equal to the string content name of the text file and then to assign the position,scaling,rotation to this object transform.

For example :
Instead :

```
transform.position = saveObject.position;
```

Then :

```
objectsToSAve[0].position = saveObject.position
```

It's just I don't know if objectsToSave[0] is the string content that was read from the text file of this transform.

This is how I'm saving :

```
public void Save()
    {
        SaveObject saveObject = new SaveObject();
        for (int i = 0; i < objectsToSave.Length; i++)
        {
            saveObject.position = objectsToSave[i].position;
            saveObject.scaling = objectsToSave[i].localScale;
            saveObject.rotation = objectsToSave[i].rotation;

            string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(saveObject);
            SaveSystem.Save(json);
        }
    }
```

This is the script attached ot empty gameobject :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SaveLoad : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform[] objectsToSave;
    public Button saveButton;

    private void Awake()
    {
        SaveSystem.Init();
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        SaveObject saveObject = new SaveObject();
        for (int i = 0; i < objectsToSave.Length; i++)
        {
            saveObject.position = objectsToSave[i].position;
            saveObject.scaling = objectsToSave[i].localScale;
            saveObject.rotation = objectsToSave[i].rotation;

            string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(saveObject);
            SaveSystem.Save(json);
        }
    }

    public void LoadSingleRecentFile()
    {
        string saveString = SaveSystem.LoadSingleRecentFile();

        if (saveString != null)
        {
            SaveObject saveObject = JsonUtility.FromJson<SaveObject>(saveString);

            transform.position = saveObject.position;
            transform.localScale = saveObject.scaling;
            transform.rotation = saveObject.rotation;
        }
    }

    public void LoadMultipleFiles()
    {
        List<string> savedStrings = SaveSystem.LoadMultipleFiles();

        for(int i = 0; i < savedStrings.Count; i++)
        {
            SaveObject saveObject = JsonUtility.FromJson<SaveObject>(savedStrings[i]);

            objectsToSave[i].position = saveObject.position;
            objectsToSave[i].localScale = saveObject.scaling;
            objectsToSave[i].rotation = saveObject.rotation;
        }
    }

    public class SaveObject
    {
        public Vector3 position;
        public Vector3 scaling;
        public Quaternion rotation;
    }
}
```

And this is where I'm doing the saving :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;

public static class SaveSystem
{
    private static readonly string SAVE_FOLDER = Application.dataPath + "/save_";
    public static void Init()
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(SAVE_FOLDER))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(SAVE_FOLDER);
        }
    }

    public static void Save(string saveString)
    {
        int saveNumber = 1;
        while (File.Exists(SAVE_FOLDER + "/" + saveNumber + ".txt"))
        {
            saveNumber++;
        }
        File.WriteAllText(SAVE_FOLDER + "/" + saveNumber + ".txt", saveString);
    }

    public static string LoadSingleRecentFile()
    {
        DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(SAVE_FOLDER);
        FileInfo[] saveFiles = directoryInfo.GetFiles("*.txt");
        FileInfo mostRecentFile = null;
        foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in saveFiles)
        {
            if (mostRecentFile == null)
            {
                mostRecentFile = fileInfo;
            }
            else
            {
                if (fileInfo.LastWriteTime > mostRecentFile.LastWriteTime)
                {
                    mostRecentFile = fileInfo;
                }
            }
        }

        if (mostRecentFile != null)
        {
            string saveString = File.ReadAllText(mostRecentFile.FullName);
            return saveString;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static List<string> LoadMultipleFiles()
    {
        DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(SAVE_FOLDER);
        FileInfo[] saveFiles = directoryInfo.GetFiles("*.txt");
        List<string> savedFiles = new List<string>();
        foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in saveFiles)
        {
            string savedFile = File.ReadAllText(fileInfo.FullName);
            if(savedFile != null)
            {
                savedFiles.Add(savedFile);
            }
        }

        return savedFiles;
    }
}
```

And a screenshot I have 3 buttons in the scene :

[image: Save system screenshot]

What I want to do is :

- When pressing the Save button save all the objects in objectsToSave List create a text file for each object in the List or one big text file for all of them using json.
- When pressing the Load Single button just load the changes made for the last gameobject now I'm doing it with LastWriteTime.
- When pressing on the button Load Multiple then load all the files that changes have made for example if I have 10 cubes and I moved two each to another position then load this two when pressing multiple depending what objects from the List have changed something position or rotation or scaling or all of them.
- To be able to press the save button to enable true/false the buttopn only if one or more objects in the List have made changes moved or rotation or scaling. If there are no changes don't allow to save so the player can't save nonstop and create nonstop save files only on changes.

Comment: With the last edit your question's scope exploded and is now in my eyes off-topic as too broad. Please stick to your original question scope and ask only one specific question at a time. I think I showed in my answer how to save and restore the values for multiple objects by name which was your original question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where you are saving the object's name. Also currently you are always saving each individual object info thus overwriting the existing save file, right?

You would probably rather do something like

```
[Serializable]
public class SaveFile
{
    public List<SaveObject> objects = new List<SaveObject>();
}

[Serializable]
public class SaveObject
{
    public string name;
    public Vector3 position;
    public Quaternion rotation;
    public Vector3 scaling;
}

public void Save()
{
    var file = new SaveFile(); 

    foreach (var obj in objectsToSave)
    {
        var saveObject = new SaveObject();
        saveObject.name = obj.name;
        saveObject.position = obj.position;
        saveObject.scaling = obj.localScale;
        saveObject.rotation = obj.rotation;
    }

    var json = JsonUtility.ToJson(file);
    SaveSystem.Save(json);
}
```

So now you have **one** file containing all objects information in a form like

```
{
    "objects" : [
        {
            "name" : "ExampleObject",
            "position" : {
                "x" : 1.2,
                "y" : 0.2,
                "z" : 0
            },
            "rotation" : ...,
            "scaling" : ...
        },
        {
            "name" : "Example2",
            ...
        }
        ...
    ]
}
```

So now when loading I assume you still have your objects in the list `objectsToSave` so you would go e.g.

```
using System.Linq;

...

public void LoadSingleRecentFile()
{
    var json = SaveSystem.LoadSingleRecentFile();

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(json))
    {
        var file = JsonUtility.FromJson<SaveFile>(json);

        foreach(var saveObject in file.objects)
        {
            // Find the object that belongs to this SaveObject
            // Either from your list
            var obj = objectsToSave.Select(o => obj.gameObject).FirstOrDefault(o => o.name.Equals(saveObject.name));
            // Or alternatively directly in the scene
            if(!obj) obj = GameObject.Find(saveObject.name);

            // Safety check
            if(!obj)
            {
                Debug.LogError($"Could not find /"{saveObject.name}/"");
                continue;
            }

            obj.transform.position = saveObject.position;
            obj.transform.localScale = saveObject.scaling;
            obj.transform.rotation = saveObject.rotation;
        }
    }
}
```

Of course this still requires the objects to have unique names.

Comment: You right I forgot to add the script and class I'm using now.  I added it now with some rules I think that should be the main logic for now.  Later I will want to extend the class in the SaveLoad script : SaveObject so I will be able to save also for exmaple camera properties values and load them and also cinemachine cameras so maybe this class should have his own module class file.

Answer (score -1):

To return the information contained in the text file use something like this if you are using python:

```
text_file = open("beer.txt", "r")
whole_thing = text_file.read()
print(whole_thing)
text_file.close()
```

In the example the file I wanted to read was `beer.txt`, and the `r` means I want to read/display the information contained in it.

Comment: Isn't this basically what OP already does in `string saveString = File.ReadAllText(mostRecentFile.FullName);
            return saveString;` ? ;) I think the title doesn't really fit with the actual question here ;)